How to derive the geometrical relationship between the Laplace equation and a rectangle with anisotropic properties?
My question is to ask how the geometrical relationships given for Equations 11-13 below were derived.
The question concerns transforming a rectangle with anisotropic properties to an isotropic parallelogram as illustrated in Figures 6a and 6b:

According to this paper (on pages 15-17), the transformation of an anisotropic rectangle to an isotropic parallelogram is found by starting with the equation (9)
$$\tag{9} k_x \ \partial ^2 \varphi/\partial x^2 + k_y \ \partial ^2 \varphi/\partial y^2 = 0$$
Here, $k_x$ and $k_y$ are principal values (eigenvalues) to the 2x2 symmetric tensor $k_{ij}$; $x$ and $y$ are Cartesian coordinates; and $\varphi$ is a scalar. The paper then goes on to say that substitution of $\bar x=x/\sqrt{k_x}$ and $\bar y=y/\sqrt{k_y}$ transforms (9) into the Laplace equation
$$\tag{10} \partial ^2 \varphi/\partial x^2 + \partial ^2 \varphi/\partial y^2 = 0$$
The paper then states that the effect of the anisotropy is thus replaced by the effect of shrinkage or expansion of the coordinates, parallel to the principal values $k_x$ and $k_y$. As a result of this substitution, the anisotropic rectangle is transformed to an isotropic parallelogram. The relations between the initial width ($W$) and length ($L$) of the rectangle, expressed by the $W/L$ ratio, the anisotropy, expressed by $k_y/k_x$ and $\phi$, and the new properties are
$$\tag{11} \frac{W'}{L'}=\frac{W}{L}\sqrt{\frac{k_y \sin^2 \phi + k_x \cos^2 \phi}{k_x \sin^2 \phi + k_y \cos^2 \phi}}$$
$$\tag{12} \pi \gamma = \arctan\left(\frac{k_y}{k_x} \tan \phi \right)+\arctan \left(\frac{k_y}{k_x} \cot \phi \right)$$
$$\tag{13} k_e=\sqrt{k_x k_y}$$
where $W'/L'$ is the ratio of the lengths of the sides of the isotropic parallelogram, $\pi \gamma$ is the smallest internal angle of the parallelogram, and $k_e$ is the equivalent isotropic $k$-value of the parallelogram.
